# Logging SEH errors in C++

Tags: c++, windows, exception

Is it possible to do the following?  I'm very new to Windows programming so what I am asking for might range from impossible to nonsensical.  If I understand correctly, errors such as division by zero or access violations are handled by the Windows structured exceptions mechanism.  I would like to dump to a log file the maximal amount of information available including preferably a stack trace when a structured exception arises.  I'm using MSVC10, windows 7.

Edit: A not unrelated question is whether this is a reasonable thing to do?  Would the stack contain enough usable information to help in debugging ie, names of functions.  Also, what is the best way do dump the stack having caught this exception?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can catch structured exceptions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681415(v=vs.85).aspx, though this old article may be the most definitive: http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/exception/exception.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. Here you can find a sample: [try-except Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s58ftw19.aspx).

But it's better to consider [dump creation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for unexpected SEH exceptions, otherwise it could be difficult to find the cause.

Comment: Thanks for the dump creation suggestion.  Is it possible for the dump to contain the stack at the moment of the call and if so, can it be function names and not addresses?

Comment: If you create PDB file for release build, you will get function names instead of addresses in call stack. Besides, dump allows you to get stack for all threads of your application.